# GLM errors " Parsing namespace 'glm' " (OSX 10.8)

Tags: macos, glm-math

I've been spending a couple of days trying to set up my project in Code::Blocks on a Macbook pro (2006) with OSX 10.8.1 (I got it for free!).

After installing Xcode, command line tools, and then restarting I got the basic gcc support (will uninstall Xcode and then just use cmd line tools when I get things working). Then I proceeded to `cmake` and `make install` GLEW, GLFW3 and GLM (GLM only needed `make install`). I then rebootet once more to get things mostly working, I'm down to four errors, and these come from the `func_trigonometric.inl` file that GLM uses. The build message is as follows:

```
/usr/local/includ... 165    current parser token 'if'
/usr/local/includ... 37     parsing namespace 'glm'
/usr/local/includ... 160    parsing function body 'tanh'
/usr/local/includ... 160    in compound statement ('{}')
                            note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.

**EDIT:**

I tried to install GLM the normal way with just dragging the folder to the location it should be in (include), the error still persists, I really need help with getting rid of this error.

Comment: So what toolchain are you using?

Comment: gcc (g++), GLEW + GLFW libraries. I also linked stdlib.h time.h vector.h, glew.h, glfw3.h and glm.hpp... I'm not sure if that's what you meant with toolchain

Comment: Why don't you use the Xcode command line tools?  They are modern, well maintained and work out-of-the-box.

Comment: I installed Xcode command line tools just to get the gcc compiler running. The reason for me wanting to use code blocks and opengl(glfw/glew combo) is that it works flawlessly on both my linux pc and windows school laptop. Also I found out I just had to use an older version of glm to get glm working (newer versions don't like osx 8.1.1 for some reason), now the compiler spews out undefined symbols for standard functions, but that's for a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was causing the errors, the version of GLM I was using was too new for OSX 8.1.1
Changing out GLM from version 9.6 to version 9.4 fixed the errors.